# Prevent Serialization of parent class Java

Tags: java, serialization

Is there a way where I can prevent the parent class to be serialized?

When we do a serialization of the subclass all the way up till the parent class the serialization is performed.

Can I restrict the serialization of the parent classes and serialize the only sub class I am working on?

Comment: any instance of sub-class is constructed by first constructing base class so wondering why would you want to serialize only sub-class and not the base class?

Comment: For your info: I rephrased my answer to make it more clear why I rejected your idea. Let me know if you find that helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* possible. Just declare your class as `implements Externalizable` and write exactly what you need in the `writeExternal()` method, taking care not to serialize anything from the superclass, and read exactly that back in the `readExternal()` method.

*Or,* just implement `Serializable` and provide your own `readObject()/writeObject()` methods, again taking care not to serialize anything from the superclass, and in this case also not calling `defaultWriteObject()` or `defaultReadObject()`.

In both cases the actual serialization of the current class's data is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is technically possible to fine tune each level of inheritance on its own - even to the extent of excluding super class fields - you might want to step back here.

Basically there are two cases:

1. The super class does not have any fields / state. Then you have nothing to exclude anyway.
2. The super class has state, represented by fields of that class.

So how do you think to meaningfully address the second part? You see when you allow deserialisation without the data for the super class fields - that means that you might have to do a lot of additional testing. To make sure that super class methods don't throw exceptions - because all of a sudden fields are null instead of being initialized.

In other words: it is possible that "leaving out" all these values - you are creating objects which behave completely different. Are you prepared for handling all the effects of that?

Meanung: skipping super class fields requires you to interfere with serialization code. It might require a lot of additional testing effort. And what do you gain? A few bytes less of data transfer at runtime.

Beyond that: what is the purpose of an inheretance hierarchy that has 4 levels - but where the super class state is irrelevant?

So my non-answer: carefully consider if your idea is really the best OO design to solve the underlying requirements.

Comment: The subclass I am using has an inheritance level of 4.So for serializing I am only concerned about the data held by my subclass.I don't want to dump the entire inheritance hierarchy of my subclass while serializing

Comment: Please see my updates. But again - what you are asking for does not make much sense. Beyond that - 4 ancestor classes has a bad design smell by its own.

Comment: Agreed.But I have no control of the class hierarchy.I am doing as per the stiplulated design,as I need to have a subclass.But if there is no way of preventing the parent class serialization..let me get back to the drawing board